# dansguardian not using syslog

Tags: syslog

I configured dansguardian to use `syslog`, but I still see files in `/var/log/dansguardian` getting populated.

I saw there was a bug for Fedora 12, I am using Fedora 20.

Is this a known issue or is it a configuration issue?

I have `syslog = on` in my configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2011/09/29/dansguardian-lessons-learned/), the setting in the DansGuardian config file `dansguardrian.conf` should be `logsyslog`, not `syslog`. So try commenting out the `syslog = on` line and add the following line instead:

```
logsyslog = on
```

It should log to `user.info`, so you'll need to edit your `syslog.conf` file to redirect that facility and level to a file or a remote server.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick.